# Will the email address I use for registering on Minecraft.net be my username?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I use an email for registering for minecraft.net to buy Minecraft,
Will my email address be my username?

For example, if I register using the email address *johnapple@example.com*, will my username be *johnapple*?

How can I choose my own username?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it won't. You will be able to choose the username you want, if it was not already taken.

Answer (score 3):

Your email will **not** be your username. You will be prompted to enter your Username later.

Comment: No problem :) Ask anything else if you want.